# .net core 3.1 Relationships between separated models

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm very confused about the way that i'm getting relationships between entitys working.
Let's image that i have a Model called Product and another called Box, and a Box have a list os Products.
I have a controller to add products and another one to add Boxes, but in the end i only want to add products to a Box which are available in the Products table.

Out the box method i found, The relationship in the model as:

```
public class Box
{ 
   (...)
   ICollection<Products> Products {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Product
{ 
   (...)
   Product Box Box {get; set;}
}
```

automatic generates a FK in the Products table with the PK of Box entity.
Is this the only way to achieve this? What is the best "way" to do it?
My concern is about how do i deal with the add/remove from the products side, as there's no singularity in it... example (when i call GET to retrieve the products via the API how do it differ the duplicated objects?)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some knowledge of the SQL lanquage and know how to use a DB management studio, the best way for you to learn EF Core code-first is a create DB tables with all foregn keys using the db management studio. After this install and use "EF Core Power Tools" to create DbContext from your DB. After this you can learn a lot about EF by comparing DB Tables and EF context.

Comment: gotcha! this is exactly what i need, the reverse process. I didn't know that it existed. Created the database in SMSS and then generate dbcontext and models from there with  the dbcontext scaffold process. Thank you!

Comment: ofc i will, :D!